# Error when getting value of radio button

Tags: jquery

What I have is a table full of check boxes, and a radio button. If any of the check boxes are checked, the radio button must also be checked or it gives an error.

My error works fine with the check box, but when I add the && condition for the radio button it always gives the error. I probably have an error in the syntax but I have tried every work around.

```
 var tablecheck = $('#mytable').find(':checked').length;
 var radiocheck = $('#myradio').find(':checked').length;

 if ((tablechecked) && (!radiocheck)){
     alert('You must pick a radio button, if you have a box checked');
}
```

Comment: Try using $('#myradio').is(':checked') to get a boolean.

Comment: That works, I don't know why i didn't try that to begin with. Thanks

Comment: What you are finding here `$('#mytable').find(':checked').length`????

Comment: I have 30 check boxes inside of a table, this just finds if any of them are checked.

Comment: It was fixed by setting the radiocheck to a boolean value

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Taplar in the comments.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mytable" /><br/>
<input type="radio" id="myradio" />
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#mytable').change(function () {
        var tablecheck = $('#mytable').is(':checked');
        var radiocheck = $('#myradio').is(':checked');

        if ((tablecheck) && (!radiocheck)) {
            alert('You must pick a radio button, if you have a box checked');

        };

    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieloshiro/c4nrgob8/)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a **typo** and *Missing Info*

```
var tablecheck = $('#mytable').find(':checked').length;//intialized "tablecheck"
if ((tablechecked) && (!radiocheck)){ //using thired form of variable
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Full code might be by utilizing [**is(:checked)**](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) :

```
var tablecheck = $('#mytable').find(':checked').length;
var radiocheck = $('#myradio').is(':checked');// also changed to correct function
if ((tablecheck) && (!radiocheck)){
   alert('You must pick a radio button, if you have a box checked');
```

Its [**Working**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mrf26za/) Fine.